# Oracle Object-Relational - PLS-00538 error and PLS-00539 error

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

Type definition:

```sql
CREATE TYPE INTERVENTO_TY AS OBJECT(
  Testo VARCHAR2(20),
  Timestmp DATE
) NOT FINAL;

CREATE TYPE COMMENTO_TY UNDER INTERVENTO_TY(
  Ordine VARCHAR2(20)
);

CREATE TYPE POST_TY UNDER INTERVENTO_TY(
  Titolo VARCHAR2(20),
  MEMBER PROCEDURE AddCom(Ordine VARCHAR2, Testo VARCHAR2, Timestmp Date)
);

CREATE TYPE AUTORE_TY AS OBJECT(
  Nome VARCHAR2(20),
  Cognome VARCHAR2(20),
  IdAutore INT
);

CREATE TYPE MEDIA_TY AS OBJECT(
  Tipo VARCHAR2(20),
  Nome VARCHAR2(20),
  IdMedia INT,
  Titolo VARCHAR2(20)
);

CREATE TYPE SCRIVE_INTERVENTO AS TABLE OF REF INTERVENTO_TY;
CREATE TYPE DI_AUTORE AS TABLE OF REF AUTORE_TY;
ALTER TYPE INTERVENTO_TY ADD ATTRIBUTE DI DI_AUTORE CASCADE;
ALTER TYPE AUTORE_TY ADD ATTRIBUTE SCRIVE SCRIVE_INTERVENTO CASCADE;
CREATE TYPE IN_INTERVENTO AS TABLE OF REF INTERVENTO_TY;
CREATE TYPE CONTIENE_MEDIA AS TABLE OF REF MEDIA_TY;
ALTER TYPE INTERVENTO_TY ADD ATTRIBUTE CONTIENE CONTIENE_MEDIA CASCADE;
ALTER TYPE MEDIA_TY ADD ATTRIBUTE IN_INT IN_INTERVENTO CASCADE;
CREATE TYPE COMMENTATO_POST AS TABLE OF REF COMMENTO_TY;
ALTER TYPE COMMENTO_TY ADD ATTRIBUTE A REF POST_TY CASCADE;
ALTER TYPE POST_TY ADD ATTRIBUTE COMMENTATO COMMENTATO_POST CASCADE;

CREATE TABLE AUTORE_TAB OF AUTORE_TY
NESTED TABLE SCRIVE STORE AS SCRIVE_NESTED;

CREATE TABLE INTERVENTO_TAB OF INTERVENTO_TY
NESTED TABLE DI STORE AS DI_NESTED
NESTED TABLE CONTIENE STORE AS CONTIENE_NESTED;

CREATE TABLE MEDIA_TAB OF MEDIA_TY
NESTED TABLE IN_INT STORE AS IN_INT_NESTED;
```

I'm trying to write an object procedure that creates a new instance of `COMMENTO_TY`, adds it to the `COMMENTO_TAB` table and the `COMMENTATO` nested table of `POST_TY`, but it gives me the following error:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE BODY Post_ty AS 
MEMBER PROCEDURE addComm(commento VARCHAR2, ordine NUMBER, IdAut INTEGER) AS
  NuovoCommento REF Commento_ty;
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO Intervento_tab I
  VALUES(Commento_ty(commento, SYSTIMESTAMP, 
                     DI_AUTORE(
                               (SELECT REF(A) FROM AUTORE_TAB A WHERE IdAutore = IdAut)
                              ),
                     CONTIENE_MEDIA(),
                     ordine,
                     (SELECT TREAT(REF(I) AS REF POST_TY)
                     FROM INTERVENTO_TAB I
                     WHERE VALUE(I) IS OF (POST_TY) AND
                           I.TIMESTMP = SELF.TIMESTMP)))
  RETURNING REF(I) INTO NuovoCommento;
  
  INSERT INTO TABLE(SELECT TREAT(VALUE(I) AS POST_TY).COMMENTATO
                    FROM INTERVENTO_TAB I
                    WHERE VALUE(I) IS OF (POST_TY)
                          AND I.TIMESTMP = SELF.TIMESTMP) 
  VALUES(NuovoCommento);
END addComm;
END;
/
```

`PLS-00538: subprogram or cursor 'ADDCOM' is declared in an object type specification and must be defined in the object type body` at line 3

`PLS-00539: subprogram 'ADDCOMM' is declared in an object type body and must be defined in the object type specification` at line 2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two errors:

```sql
PLS-00538: subprogram or cursor 'ADDCOM' is declared in an object type specification and must be defined in the object type body
```

and

```sql
PLS-00539: subprogram 'ADDCOMM' is declared in an object type body and must be defined in the object type specification
```

Notice how one is spelt `ADDCOM` and the other is `ADDCOMM`; you need to make sure the member procedure has the same name in the specification and the body.

Comment: I was so busy looking for errors in the procedure and didn't see this typo. Thank you again!